# How to set PHP alias for all users

Tags: homebrew, alias, php, mojave

This is probably easy, but I don't know how to set it for all users.

So, when I run:

```
which php
```

it shows

```
/usr/local/php5-7.2.0-20171215-181251/bin/php
```

However I've just installed PHP using brew on MacOS Mojave and I would like now also in command line to point PHP to some other directory (`/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.10/bin/php`). How can I do it for all system users?

Comment: So they all use the same shell? Also homebrew is designed to be run as the user that installed it will it run for other users?

Comment: Yes, all users use same shell. I just want to alias php so on whatever user I run `php` command it will run in fact `/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.2.10/bin/php` and not `/usr/local/php5-7.2.0-20171215-181251/bin/php` but I don't want to manually create aliases for all users